# How do I place a logo in the top left corner?

Tags: html, css

So, I am building this website for my class and the professor suggested that I should place my logo on the top left corner of my website. I have the transparent PNG and I have tried to do place it (instead of Soundwave Records as the title I want to insert my logo). I have tried to do it, but it didn't work. Ideally, whenever the user clicks on the logo, it redirects him to the HOME page.

This is the current coding for the header:

```
<header role="banner" id="home" class="site-header">
<div class="container container--max">
  <h1 class="site-header__title">
    <a href="#home" data-scroll>Soundwave Records</a>
  </h1><!-- end .site-header__title -->
```

Also, the image seems to be too big even though I have tried to resize it with Photoshop... Can't figure it out!

And this is my website: http://gabrielr.sgedu.site/final-project
Any tips/help?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me..

```
<h1 class="site-header__title">
  <a href="#home" data-scroll=""><img src="http://placehold.it/350x50"></a>
</h1>
```

If you want it to redirect to the homepage instead of a datascroll element just change the `href=` to `http://gabrielr.sgedu.site/final-project` and remove `data-scroll`

Comment: Ok, So I did it and it works... However, do you know how can I reduce the space between the logo and the hero banner immediately below.. I mean the spacing between the logo and the next container.. Link: http://gabrielr.sgedu.site/final-project/index.html

Comment: Make a new question ;)

Comment: Oh sure! Thank you again